# Easily remove GTA 5 mods

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I got a problem, where I can mod GTA 5, but not easily remove the mods for online.
It always says altered game files.
Pls help

P.S. I mean, I can remove them, but I always have to get my files verified by epic and it is just a pain in the A.

Comment: In the Steam version, I use [GTA V Mod Manager](https://www.gta5-mods.com/tools/gtav-mod-manager#description_tab) to make it easy to remove single player mods so that I can play GTA Online. However, I am not sure if this works for the Epic Games version.

Comment: I once was in this situation. I took help from my online friends who have GTA 5 to get the missing files. It worked. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯